# php FORM script not processing

Tags: php, html, forms

My form keeps redirecting back to the main contact page... so its not processing even though the submit button was pressed which mean `$_POST['contactsent']` is "yes" and the form should process.

HTML form snippet

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" value='yes' name="contactsend" />
```

PHP Form process

```
if ($_POST['contactsent'] != 'yes') {
    header ('Location: /contact');
    exit;
} else {

    if (is_array($_POST)) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
        }
    }

    $uxRequestType      = $_POST["uxRequestType"];
    $uxGlobalLocation   = $_POST["uxGlobalLocation"];
    $uxFirstName        = strtolower(str_replace("'","''",$_POST["uxFirstName"]));
    $uxFirstName        = strtoupper(substr($uxFirstName,0,1)).substr($uxFirstName,1);
    $uxLastName         = strtolower(str_replace("'","''",$_POST["uxLastName"]));
    $uxLastName         = strtoupper(substr($uxLastName,0,1)).substr($uxLastName,1);
    $uxEmail            = strtolower(str_replace("'","''",$_POST["uxEmail"]));
    $uxCity             = strtolower(str_replace("'","''",$_POST["uxCity"]));
    $uxCity             = strtoupper(substr($uxCity,0,1)).substr($uxCity,1);
    $uxState            = $_POST["uxState"];
    $uxComment          = $_POST["uxComment"];

    if ($uxGlobalLocation == "host1"):
        $SendTo="caninfo@--.com";
    elseif ($uxGlobalLocation == "host2"): 
        $SendTo="cvice@--.com";
    else:
        $SendTo="info@--.com";
    endif;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contactsend and contactsent ... Typo?

Answer (score 2):

You mis-named your variable:

```
if ($_POST['contactsent'] != 'yes') {
```

should be

```
if ($_POST['contactsend'] != 'yes') {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" value='yes' name="contactsend" />
```

and

```
if ($_POST['contactsent'] != 'yes') {
```

They both need to be "contactsend" or "contactsent"

Answer (score 1):

one key is named "contactSEND" and the other is contactSENT